Why is Magnetism at the centre of a bar magnet zero?
I have seen some sources saying

"Magnetism at the centre of a bar magnet is zero."

and Some sources say

"Magnetic field at the centre of a bar magnet is zero."

Please help me someone as they don't make any sense for me. First statement means as word Magnetism itself is some physical quantity to be measured and second statement means no Magnetic field line should pass through the central region of the bar magnet.

Please reference your sources.

The question is easy to answer if you realize that the magnetic field of a permanent magnet is caused by the alignment of the magnetic dipoles of electrons in the material. It is sufficient to remember that electrons are not only electric charges, but also magnetic dipoles to the same extent. While in non-magnetic materials the dipoles are equally distributed in all directions, in magnetic materials they have a preferred direction in total (and maintain each other in their orientations).
If you imagine this picture, you come to the conclusion that the magnetic field that you measure outside continues inside a magnet. Under no circumstances does the field inside a magnet disappear.
